# How to Instantiate AVCapturePhotoSettings( format: [string:string] )

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturephotosettings, photosui

I tried various ways to attempt to instantiate the class: AVCapturePhotoSettings to capture images in lossless BGRA format as listed below:

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : "BGRA"] )
    
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : "BGRA"] )
    
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ String( kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey) : "BGRA"] 
    
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ "kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey" : "BGRA"] )
```

The first attempt gets the compile time error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CFString' to expected dictionary key type 'String'
```

and so the three additional attempts below the first above were done, but each of these attempts got the run time error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[AVCapturePhotoSettings photoSettingsWithFormat:] Either kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey or AVVideoCodecKey must be specified'
```

What is the correct way to use this initiator for the class: AVCapturePhotoSettings ?

Comment: See the documentation for [`AVCapturePhotoSettings init(format:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1648673-init). It states that the value of the `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` key must be a value obtained from [`AVCapturePhotoOutput availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/2991116-availablephotopixelformattypes). And the value is a number, not a string.